# why do spirogyra turn brown after formation of zygospore?

Tags: sexual-reproduction

in the sexual reproduction of spirogyra, the reproductive parts of the 2 spirogyras come together to form a structure called zygospore. after this formation spirogyra turns brown. why is it so? i want to know the reason of colour change only

Comment: Can you provide a reference for this happening? Are you sure this is actually something that happens naturally versus an experimental manipulation (e.g., staining)?

Comment: my professor asked me this. He said this happens and that no one has been able to answer this. i was thinking the reason is death

Comment: "I said so" might be good enough for your professor, but it's not sufficient for this site. We expect questions to demonstrate prior research, which includes evidence that a thing happens before asking "why".

Comment: i am sorry for the inconvenience but he is not a very good teacher